How to provide a 'blanket implementation' of a static method for the derived class?
Consider this:
struct Base {
  static Base make() { return {}; }
};

struct Derived : public Base {
  // I _would_ want to have a `static Derived make()` automagically here
};

One approach to the stated problem is
struct Base {
  template <typename Self>
  static Self make() { return {}; }
};

struct Derived : public Base {
  static constexpr auto make = Base::make<Derived>;
};

, but it is not going to work with overloads, and I do need it to work with overloads...
Are there better options?

your Derived is not derived from anything

There is no way in C++ to tell a class to auto generate static class_name make() { return {}; }  And IDE might do that for you.

Try CRTP, might just work.

Unfortunately it is not possible to do what you are trying to do, but there are some alternatives depending on what you are actually aiming for in your code.
The first thing to notice is that overloading a static method is not really that interesting, since you can only call it using static dispatch anyways which pretty much defeats the point aside from code organization. To demonstrate if you had the following code (and magic_type somehow existed).
struct Base {
  static magic_type make() { return {}; }
};

struct Derived : public Base {
  static magic_type make() { return {}; }
};

You would then have to call the methods as Base::make() and Derived::make(). If this is acceptable, then I would recommend instead using template specialization.
template <typename T>
T make() {
  return T();
}

template <>
Base make<Base>() {
  return Base();
}

template <>
Derived make<Derived>() {
  return Derived();
}

Possibly in some namespace to avoid collisions with anything else named make. Then calling this code would be make<Base>() or make<Derived>() which is pretty much the same in terms of flexibility.
If what you really wanted was to override the make method, and wanted dynamic dispatch (which would mean not making the function static), then it is still not quite possible. You could use name shadowing to get code that looks roughly correct, but this is bad practice and probably does not do what you want it to (I refrain from adding an example since it should not be done and does not give you dynamic dispatch anyways). Alternatively you could return a pointer, which might be the closest solution to what your goal seems to be.
struct Base {
  std::unique_ptr<Base> make() {
    return std::make_unique<Base>();
  }
};

struct Derived : public Base {
  std::unique_ptr<Base> make() {
    return std::unique_ptr((Base*)(new (std::nothrow) Derived()));
  }
};

There is almost certainty a nicer way to do the creation of Derived but it is good enough for now.
This is definitely different than your original request, and may be unacceptable given your actual goal, but I hope one of these two possible solutions works for you or at least prompt you to find a solution for your specific use case.
